Getting error: package path is not valid. valid system image paths are:ository... null
sdkmanager build-tools 30
sdkmanager platform 30
sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86"
sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"

Everything is working fine up to here. However, when I run:
avdmanager create avd -n TestAVD -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" --device "Pixel_4"

I get this error:

error: package path is not valid. valid system image paths are:ository... null

and am unable to create AVD device.
